# Hibernate One-To-Many Mapping issue using @JoinTable

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables: User And Team

**User**

- UserId
- 4 digit Password/pin

**Team**

- Team_id
- TeamName

**Constraints**
1 user can only belong to one team whereas 1 team can have many users.
I have already normalized the database and the third table()Join Table) named user_team will be as follows:

**User_Team[JOIN TABLE]**

- User_id(This is a Foreign Key from User Table)
- Team_Id(This is a Foreign Key from Team Table)

While implementing this in Hibernate using @JoinColumn Attribute and @OneToMany annotations its throwing following error:

> A Foreign key refering com.project.hibernate.Team from
>   com.project.hibernate.User has the wrong number of column. should be 2
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A
>   Foreign key refering com.project.hibernate.Team from
>   com.project.hibernate.User has the wrong number of column. should be 2
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:657)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1610)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1335)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:800)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:725)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>   at com.project.hibernate.User_TeamDAO.main(User_TeamDAO.java:26)

Comment: In the above code, User table has user_id as PK and Team table has team_id as PK. Both Primary keys are used as Foreign Keys together as A Composite Key in Join Table User_team. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a composed key containing two fields:

```
@Id
@Column(name="team_id")
private String team_id;

@Id
@Column(name="team_name")
private String team_name;
```

Whereas your join table has only one key per table:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="user_team",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="team_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
private List<User> user;
```

You need to use all keys that make the relationship, something like that (of course table also need to have the right columns):

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="user_team",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn({@JoinColumn(name="team_id"), @JoinColumn(name="team_name")}),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
private List<User> user;
```